# How to get form on toolbar in gridpanel Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, toolbar

I have tbar in grid panel. My example code like

```
    tbar:[
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    name: 'filefor',
                    labelWidth: 50,
                    allowBlank: false,
                    buttonConfig: {
                        text: 'up...'
                    }
                }]
            }
            ,{
                text: 'add',
                handler:function(){
                        var form = this.up('form').getForm(); // not working
                        form.submit({}); // not working
                }
             }
   ]
```

I can't get my form to submit. How can i do that thanks so much :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **form** is sibling of the **add** button. you may want to use **.prev** instead of **.up** to access the form

Here is the snippet that works

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.tip.*']);

Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    var f = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;',
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            anchor: '100%',
        },
        html:'text',
        tbar: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'filefor',
                labelWidth: 50,
                allowBlank: false,
                buttonConfig: {
                    text: 'up...'
                }
            }]
        }, {
            text: 'add',
            handler: function () {
              //var form = this.prev('form').getForm(); // working at extjs4.0.2a
               var form =this.ownerCt.down('form').getForm();// working at extjs 4.2.0
               form.submit({});
            }
        }]

    });
});
```

For a live demo,  [here it is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/lianyi/6PAhQ/) .

Answer (score 2):

```
var form = this.up('form').getForm(); // not working
                    form.submit({}); // not working
change to:
this.ownerCt.down('form').getForm();
```